# ProcessMaker download pmx sample

Tags: processmaker

Is there any website where I can download ready process  scenarios for processmaker  instead of building every thing from zero.

Example full process of hiring or data update etc.

Answer (score 1):

Great question.  We just released a process template library feature into the product in our Spring release.  You can see the available templates [here](https://www.processmaker.com/resources/customer-success/templates/). You can now import templates and also create your own templates and share with others in your organization.  Also, you might want to watch the entire [Spring Release presentation](https://www.processmaker.com/resources/customer-success/webinars/processmaker-platform-2023-spring-release/) because there are loads of other exciting new features.

Comment: Thanks, is these templates compatible with ProcessMaker 3.8?